# FME- Process feature one by one

Tags: gis, arcgis, fme

How to process features in FME one by one For Example:- Take all the data of one country add certain data and write in FGDB, then take data of another country and then process it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, what you're looking for is batch processing different files. In that case I think the easiest approach is tu use a WorkspaceRunner in a parent workspace that calls a child workspace that does the processing. In this FME Community example you can find more information on how to build it: https://community.safe.com/s/article/batch-processing-using-the-workspacerunner-1